# Programa en ASP.NET no regresa datos del cliente

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cliente

Estoy realizando un e-commerce con ASP.NET en Visual Studio 2022 y a la hora de usar el metodo Listar que cree no me devuelve ningun dato de los clientes, solamente me arroja "null" en todos los atributos.
Si alguien me podria ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho! Abajo dejo todo detallado.

Este es el codigo:

Tabla de clase Clientes en la base de datos:

```
create table clientes(
id_cliente int primary key identity,
nombre varchar(60),
apellido varchar(60),
correo varchar(100),
contrasenia varchar(100),
codigo_postal int foreign key references ciudades(codigo_postal),
telefono varchar(60),
reestablecer bit default 0,
fecha_registro datetime default getdate())
```

Clientes en CapaEntidad del proyecto:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CapaEntidad
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        public int id_cliente { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellido { get; set; }
        public string correo { get; set; }
        public string contrasenia { get; set; }
        public string confirmarcontrasenia { get; set; }
        public Ciudades oCiudades { get; set; }
        public string telefono { get; set; }
        public bool reestablecer { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Clientes en CapaDatos del proyecto:

```
using CapaEntidad;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CapaDatos
{
    public class CD_Cliente
    {

        public List<Cliente> Listar()
        {
            List<Cliente> lista = new List<Cliente>();


            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion.cn))
                {

                    string query = "select id_cliente, nombre, apellido, correo, contrasenia, codigo_postal, telefono, reestablecer from clientes";

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, oconexion);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    oconexion.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {

                            lista.Add(
                                new Cliente()
                                {
                                    id_cliente = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_cliente"]),
                                    nombre = dr["nombre"].ToString(),
                                    apellido = dr["apellido"].ToString(),
                                    correo = dr["correo"].ToString(),
                                    contrasenia = dr["contrasenia"].ToString(),
                                    oCiudades = new Ciudades
                                    {
                                        codigo_postal = Convert.ToInt32(dr["codigo_postal"])
                                    },
                                    telefono = dr["telefono"].ToString(),
                                    reestablecer = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["reestablecer"]),
                                }
                                );

                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            catch
            {
                lista = new List<Cliente>();
            }

            return lista;
        }

        public int Registrar(Cliente obj, out string Mensaje)
        {
            int idautogenerado = 0;
            Mensaje = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion.cn))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_RegistrarCliente", oconexion);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nombres", obj.nombre); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Apellidos", obj.apellido); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Correo", obj.correo); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Clave", obj.contrasenia); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CodigoPostal", obj.oCiudades.codigo_postal); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Telefono", obj.telefono); 
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Mensaje", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Resultado", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    oconexion.Open();

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    idautogenerado = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["Resultado"].Value); // Cambiar "Resultado" a "@Resultado"
                    Mensaje = cmd.Parameters["Mensaje"].Value.ToString(); // Cambiar "Mensaje" a "@Mensaje"
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                idautogenerado = 0;
                Mensaje = ex.Message;
            }
            return idautogenerado;
        }


     

        public bool CambiarClave(int idcliente, string nuevaclave, out string Mensaje)
        {
            bool resultado = false;
            Mensaje = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion.cn))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update clientes set contrasenia = @nuevaclave, reestablecer = 0 where id_cliente = @id", oconexion);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idcliente);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nuevaclave", nuevaclave);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    oconexion.Open();
                    resultado = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 ? true : false; // si la cantidad de filas afectadas es mayor a 0 salio todo bien, sino hubo un error
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                resultado = false;
                Mensaje = ex.Message;
            }
            return resultado;
        }

        public bool ReestablecerClave(int idcliente, string clave, out string Mensaje)
        {
            bool resultado = false;
            Mensaje = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion.cn))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update clientes set contrasenia = @clave, reestablecer = 1 where id_cliente = @id", oconexion);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idcliente);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clave", clave);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    oconexion.Open();
                    resultado = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 ? true : false; // si la cantidad de filas afectadas es mayor a 0 salio todo bien, sino hubo un error al eliminar el usuario
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                resultado = false;
                Mensaje = ex.Message;
            }
            return resultado;
        }

    }
}
```

Clientes en CapaNegocio del proyecto:

```
using CapaDatos;
using CapaEntidad;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CapaNegocio
{
    public class CN_Cliente
    {



        private CD_Cliente objCapaDato = new CD_Cliente();

        public List<Cliente> Listar()
        {
            return objCapaDato.Listar();
        }





        private bool ExisteCodigoPostalEnBaseDeDatos(int codigoPostal)
        {
            using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion.cn))
            {
                string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ciudades WHERE codigo_postal = @CodigoPostal";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, oconexion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodigoPostal", codigoPostal);

                oconexion.Open();

                int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                return count > 0;
            }
        }


        public int Registrar(Cliente obj, out string Mensaje)
        {
            Mensaje = string.Empty;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.nombre) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj.nombre))
            {
                Mensaje = "El nombre del cliente no puede estar vacío";
                return 0; // Retorna 0 para indicar un error
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.apellido) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj.apellido))
            {
                Mensaje = "El apellido del cliente no puede estar vacío";
                return 0; // Retorna 0 para indicar un error
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.correo) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj.correo))
            {
                Mensaje = "El correo del cliente no puede estar vacío";
                return 0; // Retorna 0 para indicar un error
            }
            else if (obj.oCiudades == null || !ExisteCodigoPostalEnBaseDeDatos(obj.oCiudades.codigo_postal))
            {
                Mensaje = "El código postal es incorrecto";
                return 0; // Retorna 0 para indicar un error
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.telefono) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj.telefono))
            {
                Mensaje = "El teléfono del cliente no puede estar vacío";
                return 0; // Retorna 0 para indicar un error
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mensaje))
            {
                obj.contrasenia = CN_Recursos.ConvertirSha256(obj.contrasenia);
                return objCapaDato.Registrar(obj, out Mensaje);
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        // CAMBIAR CONTRASEÑA
        public bool CambiarClave(int idcliente, string nuevaclave, out string Mensaje)
        {
            return objCapaDato.CambiarClave(idcliente, nuevaclave, out Mensaje);
        }


        // REESTABLECER CONTRASEÑA
        public bool ReestablecerClave(int idcliente, string correo, out string Mensaje)
        {
            Mensaje = string.Empty;
            string nuevaclave = CN_Recursos.GenerarClave();
            bool resultado = objCapaDato.ReestablecerClave(idcliente, CN_Recursos.ConvertirSha256(nuevaclave), out Mensaje);

            if (resultado) // mensaje que se muestra al usuario
            {
                string asunto = "Contraseña Reestablecida";
                string mensaje_correo = "<h3>Su cuenta fue reestablecida correctamente</h3></br><p>Su contraseña para acceder ahora es: !clave!</p>";
                mensaje_correo = mensaje_correo.Replace("!clave!", nuevaclave);

                bool respuesta = CN_Recursos.EnviarCorreo(correo, asunto, mensaje_correo);

                if (respuesta)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Mensaje = "No se pudo enviar el correo";
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Mensaje = "No se pudo reestablecer la contraseña";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En el Controller llamado "Acceso" realizo el siguiente HttpPost:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string correo, string clave)
        {
            Cliente oCliente = new Cliente();

            oCliente = new CN_Cliente().Listar().Where(u => u.correo == correo && u.contrasenia == CN_Recursos.ConvertirSha256(clave)).FirstOrDefault(); 

            if (oCliente == null)   // validar si se encontro un usuario

            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Correo o contraseña incorrectos";
                return View();
            }
            else
            {

                if (oCliente.reestablecer) // el usuario debe reestablecer la contraseña
                {

                    TempData["IdCliente"] = oCliente.id_cliente;

                    return RedirectToAction("CambiarClave");
                }

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(oCliente.correo, false);

                ViewBag.Error = null;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

Este es el html de Index:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body class="bg-primary">
    <div id="layoutAuthentication">
        <div id="layoutAuthentication_content">
            <main>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <div class="card shadow-lg border-0 rounded-lg mt-5">
                                <div class="card-header"><h3 class="text-center font-weight-light my-4">Login</h3></div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <form action="@Url.Action("Index","Acceso")" method="post">
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                            <input class="form-control" name="correo" type="email" />
                                            <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                            <input class="form-control" name="clave" type="password" />
                                            <label for="inputPassword">Contraseña</label>
                                        </div>

                                        @{

                                            if (ViewBag.Error != null)
                                            {
                                                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                                        @ViewBag.Error
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            }

                                        }

                                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-4 mb-0">
                                            <a class="small" href="@Url.Action("Reestablecer", "Acceso")">¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?</a>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Iniciar Sesión</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer text-center py-3">
                                    <div class="small"><a href="@Url.Action("Registrar","Acceso")">¿No tienes una cuenta? ¡Registrate aqui!</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
        <div id="layoutAuthentication_footer">
            <footer class="py-4 bg-light mt-auto">
                <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between small">
                        <div class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2023</div>
                        <div>
                            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                            &middot;
                            <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en todo este codigo (esta bien que pongas el contexto, vos pusiste demasiado, cosas que nada que ver con tu problema...) la lista que llenas, se llena, o ni siquiera se llena???